# Owin UseOAuthBearerAuthentication Not getting groups claims

Tags: single-sign-on, owin, okta

I am not getting any group claims back from Okta when authenticating using the `id_token`. I am getting the name, email, address, and username, but no groups.

Not sure what else I would need to do to get this onto the principle

```
var clientID = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"];

var oidcIssuer = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OIDC_Issuer"];

TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = clientID,

        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = oidcIssuer,

        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),

    };

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps,
        new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(oidcIssuer + "/.well-known/openid-configuration")),
    });
```

Comment: Are these groups imported from Active Directory or groups created directly in Okta?

Comment: Created in Okta

Comment: If you use .* in the Group setting for the OIDC Application, this will return all groups a User is a member of. It basically uses regex to return groups